# ejabberd reports bad request/modify when attempting to delete user

Tags: runtime-error, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I'm trying to delete user using ejabberd yet I'm receiving 400/modify bad-request error. The stanzas sent by Smack are by the spec [1] as far as I can tell; it also works fine with OpenFire.

Ejabberd runs in rroemhild/docker-ejabberd docker container version 17.03-1 (the latest available; for reasons why I am not using the processone container see [2]) with the config file being stock from there (sections removed; full copy at [3])

`hosts:
  - "xmppserver.com"
auth_method:
  - internal
acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin": "xmppserver.com"
      - "adminaccount": "xmppserver.com"
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
access:
(nothing of interest here)
modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
host_config:
  "xmppserver.com":
    domain_certfile: "/opt/ejabberd/ssl/xmppserver.com.pem"`

*(Yes, I will properly configure SSL once I verify it works for me)*

First I confirm the user is authorised to issue admin commands:

**SENT**

`<iq to='xmppserver.com' id='Ghtu9-15' type='get'>
    <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands'/>
</iq>`

**RECEIVED**

`<iq xml:lang='en' to='appserver@xmppserver.com/39058022031067483561501494598609310' from='xmppserver.com' type='result' id='Ghtu9-15'>
    <query node='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'>
        ...
        <item node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#add-user' name='Add User' jid='xmppserver.com'/>
        <item node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#delete-user' name='Delete User' jid='xmppserver.com'/>
        ...
    </query>
</iq>`

As you can see the delete-user command is listed as available. Then I proceed to delete a user:

**SENT**

`<iq to='xmppserver.com' id='2vM3f-17' type='set'>
    <command xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands' action='execute' node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#delete-user'></command>
</iq>`

**RECEIVED**

`<iq xml:lang='en' to='adminaccount@xmppserver.com/163923254889085958281501260654263394' from='xmppserver.com' type='result' id='2vM3f-17'>
    <command status='executing' sessionid='2017-07-28T16:51:12.784282Z' node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#delete-user' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands'>
        <actions execute='complete'>
            <complete/>
        </actions>
        <x type='form' xmlns='jabber:x:data'>
            <title>Delete User</title>
            <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
                <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/admin</value>
            </field>
            <field var='accountjids' type='jid-multi' label='Jabber ID'>
                <required/>
            </field>
        </x>
    </command>
</iq>`

Here I'm not sure what the <actions...> tag is about; it's not mentioned in XEP-133. Other than that the form looks good.

**SENT**

`<iq to='xmppserver.com' id='2vM3f-19' type='set'>
    <command xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands' sessionid='2017-07-28T16:51:12.784282Z' node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#delete-user'>
        <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
            <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
                <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/admin</value>
            </field>
            <field var='accountjids' type='jid-multi'>
                <value>jid@xmppserver.com</value>
            </field>
        </x>
    </command>
</iq>`

**RECEIVED**

`<iq xml:lang='en' to='adminaccount@xmppserver.com/163923254889085958281501260654263394' from='xmppserver.com' type='error' id='2vM3f-19'>
    <command sessionid='2017-07-28T16:51:12.784282Z' node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#delete-user' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands'>
        <x type='submit' xmlns='jabber:x:data'>
            <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
                <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/admin</value>
            </field>
            <field var='accountjids' type='jid-multi'>
                <value>jid@xmppserver.com</value>
            </field>
        </x>
    </command>
    <error code='400' type='modify'>
        <bad-request xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
    </error>
</iq>`

I also tried sending bare JIDs (i.e. without the hostname part) but the result is the same.

This is not a particularly helpful error message.

What am I doing wrong?

[1] https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html#delete-user

[2] https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/1890

[3] https://pastebin.com/5D0rEbFR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently <error code='400' type='modify'> is eJabberD's way of saying 'user not found, nothing to delete'.